# inject implementation to a single multi-function interface class - many CRTP classes?

Tags: c++, interface, c++14, crtp, vtable

How to create **many** classes to act like implementer for an interface class, while avoid v-table cost as possible, and still enable static casting to the interface?

For a simple case, it can be achieved like in the below example.

### Example

**Library Code** :-

```
class I{ //interface
    public: virtual void i1()=0;
};
template<class Derived>class Router : public I{ 
    public: virtual void  i1()final{   
        //in real case it is very complex, but in the core is calling :-
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->u1(); 
    }
};
```

**User Code** :-

```
class User : public Router<User>{
    public: void u1(){ std::cout<<"hi"<<std::endl; }
};
int main() {
    User u;
    u.i1();   //<-- no v-table cost
    I* i=&u;
    i->i1();  //<-- has v-table cost (OK)
}
```

[image]

[Full demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa5547c6c83fd484)

### Question

How to extend the above feature to support 2 routes or more?
[image]

The below code is uncompilable, but it depicts my dream. ([full demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/21bd23f8cee55c68)).

**Library Code** :-

```
class I{ //interface
    public: virtual void i1()=0;
    public: virtual void i2()=0;
};
template<class Derived>class RouterI1U1 : public I{ 
    public: virtual void  i1()final{ static_cast<Derived*>(this)->u1(); }
};
template<class Derived>class RouterI1U2 : public I{ 
    public: virtual void  i1()final{ static_cast<Derived*>(this)->u2(); }
};
template<class Derived>class RouterI2U1 : public I{ 
    public: virtual void  i2()final{ static_cast<Derived*>(this)->u1(); }
};
template<class Derived>class RouterI2U2 : public I{ 
    public: virtual void  i2()final{ static_cast<Derived*>(this)->u2(); }
};
```

**User Code** :-

The one who want to use the above library, can **easily** pick whatever "route" he want.

- derived from `RouterI1U2<User>` and `RouterI2U1<User>` or
- derived from `RouterI1U1<User>` and `RouterI2U2<User>` or
- derived from {`RouterI1U1<User>` or `RouterI1U2<User>`} and implement `i2()` with final manually or
- derived from {`RouterI2U2<User>` or `RouterI2U1<User>`} and implement `i1()` with final manually or
- implement `i1()` and `i2()` with final manually

Here is an dreamed example of usage.

```
class User : public RouterI1U2<User>,public RouterI2U1<User>{ 
    public: void u1(){ std::cout<<"hi1"<<std::endl; }
    public: void u2(){ std::cout<<"hi2"<<std::endl; }
};
int main() {
    User u;
    u.i1();   //<-- no v-table cost
    I* i=&u;
    i->i1();  //<-- has v-table cost (OK)
}
```

### My poor solution

```
class I{ //interface
    public: virtual void i1()=0;
    public: virtual void i2()=0;
};

template<class Derived> class RouterI1U2_I2U1 : public I{ //group it
    public: virtual void  i1()final{ static_cast<Derived*>(this)->u2(); }
    public: virtual void  i2()final{ static_cast<Derived*>(this)->u1(); }
};
class User : public RouterI1U2_I2U1<User>{ 
    public: void u1(){ std::cout<<"hi1"<<std::endl; }
    public: void u2(){ std::cout<<"hi2"<<std::endl; }
};
```

It works ([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f132883d32606e35)), but offer less modularity.   (low re-usability)
 I have to pack `RouterI1U2` and `RouterI2U1` to `RouterI1U2_I2U1`  manually.

Answer (score 3):

It may not apply in your case, but could be useful to other reading the question as well.

I suggest you to use the concept-model idiom for this particular case. The goal of this is to separate the polymorphism implementation and the implementation of those class themselves into different part. Here, `I` becomes a polymorphic wrapper around any class that has `i1` and `i2` member functions:

```
class I {
    // The interface is internal, invisible to outside
    // We use this as a type erasure technique and polymorphism
    struct Concept {
        virtual void i1() = 0;
        virtual void i2() = 0;
    };

    // The single implementation that directly
    // extend the interface is the model. T is the user class.
    // T must have i1 and i2 function, because we call them.
    template<typename T>
    struct Model : Concept {

        // The user class.
        // If you want, you can use a reference there if you
        // need references semantics with I
        T user;

        Model (T u) : user{std::move(u)} {}

        // The only implementation of i1 is to call i1 from the user class
        void i1() override {
            user.i1();
        }

        void i2() override {
            user.i2();
        }
    };

    // Or use a shared, or use SBO
    std::unique_ptr<Concept> concept;

public:
    // When we make an I, we must provide a user class.
    // If the user class had i1 and i2, it will compile.
    // If Model takes a reference, use a reference there too.
    template<typename T>
    I(T model) : concept{std::make_unique<Model<T>>(std::move(model))} {}

    void i1() {
        concept->i1();
    }

    void i2() {
        concept->i2();
    }
};
```

Then, your classes that provide implementations becomes like this:

```
template<class Derived>
struct RouterI1U1 { // no Inheritance needed
    void i1() { static_cast<Derived*>(this)->u1(); }
};

template<class Derived>
struct RouterI1U2 { 
    void i1() { static_cast<Derived*>(this)->u2(); }
};

template<class Derived>
struct RouterI2U1 { 
    void i2() { static_cast<Derived*>(this)->u1(); }
};

template<class Derived>
struct RouterI2U2 { 
    void i2() { static_cast<Derived*>(this)->u2(); }
};
```

Since these `i1` and `i2` only needs to be "there" in order to fit into the `Model<T>` class, no overriding is needed, so no virtual inheritance.

It would effectively look like this when used:

```
struct User : RouterI2U2<User> {
    void i1() {}
    void u2() {}
};
```

As you can see, we don't have any virtual method. The polymorphism is an implementation detail of `I`. Since this class have all required member functions, the `I` class will allow it.

And using the class `I` too is quite simple. Let `User2` be another user class that fits `I` requirements:

```
User2 user2;

user2.i1(); // no vtable, so no vtable overhead possible

I myI{user2}; // works!

myI.i2(); // calls u2, with vtable

std::vector<I> v;

v.emplace_back(User2{});
v.emplace_back(User{}); // simple heh?
```

---

Here's how you can remove the router classes, and implement this thing with an "or" style interface. I mean an interface that allows you to implement something *or* something else.

In the `Model<T>` class, you can check if `i1` and `i2` exists. If there are not existing, you can provide an implementation that calls `u1` and `u2` instead.

We start that by making type traits that can tell us if a particular type `T` has the member function `i1` or `i2`:

```
template<typename...>
using void_t = void;

template<typename, typename>
struct has_i1 : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct has_i1<T, void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().i1())>> : std::true_type {};

template<typename, typename>
struct has_i2 : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct has_i2<T, void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().i2())>> : std::true_type {};
```

Now, we can change our model implementation to call `u1` or `u2` if `i1` and `i2` are not there:

```
template<typename T>
struct Model : Concept {
    T user;

    Model(T u) : user{std::move(u)} {}


    void i1() override {
        i1_helper(user);
    }

    void i2() override {
        i2_helper(user);
    }

private:
    template<typename U>
    auto i1_helper(U& u) -> std::enable_if_t<has_i1<U>::value> {
        // Call i1 if has i1
        u.i1();
    }

    template<typename U>
    auto i1_helper(U& u) -> std::enable_if_t<!has_i1<U>::value> {
        // Call u1 if has not i1
        u.u1();
    }

    template<typename U>
    auto i2_helper(U& u) -> std::enable_if_t<has_i2<U>::value> {
        // Call i2 if has i2
        u.i2();
    }

    template<typename U>
    auto i2_helper(U& u) -> std::enable_if_t<!has_i2<U>::value> {
        // Call u2 if has not i2
        u.u2();
    }
};
```

Now, your user classes are the simplest possible.

```
struct User1 {
    void i1() {}
    void i2() {}
};

struct User2 {
    void i1() {}
    void u2() {}
};

struct User3 {
    void u1() {}
    void i2() {}
};

 struct User4 {
    void u1() {}
    void u2() {}
};
```

Comment: Interesting indeed.  With this approach, the multiple inheritance is very clean. I feel it like making a custom virtual inheritance by hand, so it is more controllable.  All dirty jobs are moved into a single place, hence more maintainability. Thank.

Comment: CRTP is really flexible, too, this is not your only option. If I recall correctly there are a couple of ways you can get around all the `void i1() { static_cast<Derived*>(this)->u1(); }` repetition. In my active project I have `bool update(Updatable<T> &u)` that calls the `update` method of the `static_cast`-ed u, and `Updatable<T>` is just a *promise* to implement `update()`. If that promise is not kept, this results in a substitution failure, and you can decide whether a default candidate or compiler error is more appropriate. Try nesting/chaining/`common_type`/etc. once you've gotten it!

Answer (score 1):

Use virtual inheritance.

```
template<class Derived>class RouterI1U1 : public virtual I{
```

etc. makes the code compilable.

Comment: It works ([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a9e7b1ccb287aa68)).  .....   Will `u.i1();` still suffer no v-table cost, and `i->i1();` suffer the same level of v-table cost?  (praising the great n.m.)

Comment: Oh, this way, I can't `User* uPtr=static_cast<User*>(i);`.   ... I never mentioned that I want it though.  I probably don't need it.  :)

Comment: Yes, you would need a dynamic cast.

Comment: As for costs, I believe  u.i1() will still incur no vtable cost, and i->i1() may incur slightly higher cost because of a thunk.